# Mysql "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" should not stop execution when file does not exist

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We have several CSV files which we load into our database. They are provided by an external party. Because of reasons unknown to me they sometimes split data into two files, sometimes it is one file. How can I load the "optional" file (here `a_2.txt`) only if the files exists or convince `LOAD DATA INFILE` to not stop the execution of my script?

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/foo/a_1.txt"
INTO TABLE 
``table_a` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/foo/a_2.txt"
INTO TABLE 
`table_a` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/foo/b.txt"
INTO TABLE 
`table_b` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: Are you running this script using the mysql client? There's a [--force option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_force) to make it continue if it gets an error on a single SQL statement.

Comment: If you're running this from a script, the script could check for the file before sending the command.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas! Actually I don't think it's bad that the script stops if there is a REAL issue... New idea which I want to try: First create empty files with the expected names, then unzip the data (and by this overwrite the empty files), then run the import. Maybe this works.